# pdoResources вывод товаров из той же категории

Tags: modx, revo

На сайте есть категории, в каждой категории — товары. В карточке товара надо вывести список других товаров из той же категории.

Подскажите, возможно ли вывести товары из той же категории без применения tvFilters, указав что-то в pdoResources &parents="?". Или каким-то другим способом?

Я сейчас использую следующий вызов:

```
[[!pdoResources?
    &parents=`[[*id]]`
    &limit=`5`
    &tpl=`Tpl`
    &sortby=`RAND()`
]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструкция [parent](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/commonly-used-template-tags) (`[[*parent]]`) возвращает `id` родительского ресурса.

Соответственно, в вашем случаи запись будет такой:

```
[[!pdoResources?
    &parents=`[[*parent]]`
    &limit=`5`
    &tpl=`Tpl`
    &sortby=`RAND()`
]]
```

Comment: Благодарю! Это то, что нужно.